# PlayRunHook afterStopped method not being called on Windows

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm implementing the Play framework's `PlayRunHook` trait and overriding the `afterStarted` and `afterStopped` methods like this:

```
object PlayHooks extends PlayRunHook {
    override def afterStarted(add: InetSocketAddress): Unit = {
        println("started")
    }

    override def afterStopped(): Unit = {
        println("stopped")
    }
}
```

On a Linux machine, both hooks are called as expected (the former at `sbt run` and the latter on `CTRL + D` or `CTRL + C`).

On Windows, the `afterStarted` hook is called but when I stop sbt, it stops immediately and doesn't call the `afterStopped` method at all. If I run it with a debugger, a breakpoint in the `afterStopped` method never gets hit.

Is there some Windows-specific thing I need to do for this to work?

Comment: Curious if you've found a resolution for this. For me, the `afterStopped` seems to be called appropriately if you shut Play down with `Enter`, but isn't called when shut down with `Ctrl + C`